How to remove session id in logout?
I have a problem: when I do logout in Django I can still see a session id cookie in my browser and even after login I can acess an index page which is decorated with login_required. Please see the code below.
@login_required(login_url='signin')
def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return redirect('signin')

@login_required(login_url='signin')
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

I am quite frustrated and do not get what is misconfiured, chat gpt is suggesting some garbage(as ususal)
Tried to remove session manually, tried to flush and so on - nothing works in chrome and safari

Are you using a custom authentication backend? What does your middleware settings look like?

@Vegard no custom authentication. Which settings exactly do you need? I haven't done any specific configuration related to authentication

Why do you make a custom logout?

@willeM_VanOnsem I would prefer not to do it. I assume there should be some standard way to resolve my issue - probably I am missing something

@AlexBondar: the exact reason to use a LogoutView is because later on, a bug, security vulnerability, etc. might be discovered, then that is fixed in the LogoutView, so all Django projects that depend on the LogoutView got fixed when they upgrade.

@willeM_VanOnsem could you please elaborate more regarding this view or maybe add a response with a tiny code snippet in order I could get an idea?

How do you log a user in? And in your settings.py, what does the MIDDLEWARE list look like?

@Vegard MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

@Vegard        auth.login(request, user)
